# Sql query to find cheapest product from given data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in following format

```
Id,Vendor,Product Name,Product Code,Unit,Weight,Price

1,Vendor1,Coriander Leaves (April-Nov),3736,Kg,3,90

2,Vendor1,Mint Leaves 500 Gm,4371,Grams,500,27.5

3,Vendor1,Ginger 500 Gm,4356,Grams,500,29.5

4,Vendor1,Lemon 500 Gm,4365,Grams,500,32.5

5,Vendor2,Coriander Leaves (April-Nov),3736,Kg,3,80

6,Vendor2,Mint Leaves 500 Gm,4371,Grams,500,27.5

7,Vendor2,Ginger 500 Gm,4356,Grams,500,30

8,Vendor2,Lemon 500 Gm,4365,Grams,500,31

9,Vendor3,Coriander Leaves (April-Nov),3736,Kg,3,88

10,Vendor3,Mint Leaves 500 Gm,4371,Grams,500,27.3

11,Vendor3,Ginger 500 Gm,4356,Grams,500,29.7

12,Vendor3,Lemon 500 Gm,4365,Grams,500,34.5
```

I want to generate a product list based on:

- cheapest prices
- expensive prices

For example, for cheapest prices, we would get a list like:

3,Vendor1,Ginger 500 Gm,4356,Grams,500,29.5

5,Vendor2,Coriander Leaves (April-Nov),3736,Kg,3,80

8,Vendor2,Lemon 500 Gm,4365,Grams,500,31

10,Vendor3,Mint Leaves 500 Gm,4371,Grams,500,27.3

I ran following query for cheapest prices

```
SELECT ID,DISTINCT VENDOR,productname,productcode,unit,weight,min(price) 
from vendor_price_list 
group by productcode;
```

but getting error:-

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DISTINCT
>   VENDOR,productname,productcode,unit,weight,min(price) from
>   vendor_price' at line 1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you happen to Google the syntax for how to use DISTINCT?

Comment: The ´DISTINCT´ clause cannot be used in the middle of the columns of the ´SELECT´ statement

Answer (score 1):

Find the max price, then join

```
select a2.*
from
(select productcode, max(price) as m_price -- Swap this for min(price) for minimum
from vendor_price_list 
group by productcode) a1
inner join vendor_price_list a2
  on a2.productcode = a1.productcode
  and a2.price = a1.m_price
```